# jQuery ui.index is always undefined

Tags: jquery, user-interface, indexing

I have a problem when i try to remember the last clicked tab in jQuery. I want to use ui.index in the javascript code, but i found it always get undefined.

Here is my code:

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
  var newIndex = ui.index;
  $("#<%=hiddenSelectedTab.ClientID%>").val(newIndex);
});
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks

**Edit:**

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#link1">
             link1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#link2">
             link2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#link3">
             link3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="link1"></div>
    <div id="link2"></div>
    <div id="link3"></div>
</div>
```

I use a hiddenField to remember the tab i choosed.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenSelectedTab" runat="server" value="0" />
```

My javascript code modified:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs().tabs('select', parseInt($("#<%=hiddenSelectedTab.ClientID%>").val()));
            var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
            var selected = $tabs.tabs("option", "selected");
            $("#<%=hiddenSelectedTab.ClientID%>").val(selected);
});
```

This line always return 0.

```
var selected = $tabs.tabs("option", "selected");
```

I'm really confused. :(

Comment: can you post some of your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remember last selected tab after browser close you should use cookie. if you want to remember selected tab without browser closing this COMPLETE code working for me:(if you want to use hidden input)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"/> 
</head>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#link1">
             link1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#link2">
             link2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#link3">
             link3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="link1"></div>
    <div id="link2"></div>
    <div id="link3"></div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenSelectedTab"  value="2" />
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert($("#hiddenSelectedTab").val());
$("#tabs").tabs().tabs({
selected:parseInt($("#hiddenSelectedTab").val()),
select: function(event, ui) { 
alert(ui.index);
$("#hiddenSelectedTab").val(ui.index);
alert($("#hiddenSelectedTab").val());
}
});
});
</script>
```

after browser "alert 2" after select 1th tabs "alert 0" two times

Comment: I've tested your code, it worked perfectly. There is something wrong with my code, and i have to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

use cookie . check [this link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie)

function is like:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        cookie: {
            // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
            expires: 1
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Do you mean there is not a solution with event?

Comment: i am not sure  but cookie do that.

Comment: But it will be more complex and heavy for me. I am trying to solve it with the second method hunter said. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs").tabs().tabs('select',$("#hiddenSelectedTab").val());
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs("option", "selected");
$("#<%=hiddenSelectedTab.ClientID%>").val("selected");
```

I got a problem with

```
parseInt($("#<%=hiddenSelectedTab.ClientID%>").val())
```

and replace with

```
$("#hiddenSelectedTab").val()
```

and it works!

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try it tommorrow, coz the code is in the company.

Comment: For the line `var selected = $tabs.tabs("option", "selected");`, the value of selected is always 2. Do you know why?

Comment: It always get the value of last tab.

Comment: for me alert(selected) return zero based seleted tab. for example if hiddenSelectedTab is 2 alert 1 (zero based)

Comment: another code :                                  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs().tabs({
selected:parseInt($("#hiddenSelectedTab").val()),
select: function(event, ui) { 
alert(ui.index);
$("#hiddenSelectedTab").val(ui.index);
alert($("#hiddenSelectedTab").val());//last clicked tab zero based
}
});
});

Comment: I tried your code. When i click the first tab, it displays `0` and after `undefined`. when i click the second tab, it displays `1` and then display `undefined`.

Comment: add <input type="hidden" id="hiddenSelectedTab"  value="2" />

Comment: It redirects to the last tab all the time. And before, i've used `<input type="hidden" id="hiddenSelectedTab" runat="server" value="0" />`, so it always redirect to the first tab. Really confused...